# How to fix the OpenWheather API's opaque response in RactiveJs with HTML5 Fetch API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html, ractivejs

This is the first time we're **dirtifying** our hands with [Fetch HTML5 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [Ractive JS](http://www.ractivejs.org/).

We've [this code here](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/boe2vcj6/) which is not throwing any error.

<strike>Notice the `no-cors` header set as the request parameter.</strike>

> We just need to get the free API data from the [Open Weather Map guys](http://openweathermap.org/current).

How to fix that opaque response in RactiveJs with HTML5 Fetch API

Comment: `Notice the no-cors header set as the request parameter.` - this ensures your code wont be able to access any response, is that what you want?

Comment: @JaromandaX Nope sir, we need to access the response. I added it to supress the error :(

Comment: suppressing a cors error doesn't bypass cors! Looks like that API doesn't issue any cors headers, so you wont be able to access that API directly through the browser

Comment: @JaromandaX So what is the other possibility sir?

Comment: 1. proxy through your own server. 2. does the API support JSONP (you wont use fetch in that case) ... another issue is that you aren't using fetch correctly. The result of fetch is a `response object`, you then need to process the response to get the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs to correct the following errors

1. use `api.openweathermaps.org` not `sample.openweathermaps.org`
2. use `GET` not `POST`
3. use a **VALID** api key (yes, you can get a free key)
4. use fetch correctly

---

```
fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=**valid api key**', {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.dir(data));
```